# Fortran Bus Error on allocating a large matrix (gfortran)

Tags: memory-management, fortran, fortran95

When I compile the following Fortran code with gfortran and run it, it gives me 'signal SIGBUS: Access to undefined portion of a memory object', whenever n>=180. I'm running this on a Mac OSX Mavericks.

```
PROGRAM almatrix
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: i,j,n
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE :: a(:,:)
  READ(*,*)n
  ALLOCATE(a(n+1,n+1))
  DO i=0,n
    DO j=0,n
      a(i,j)=0.0
    END DO
  END DO
  DEALLOCATE(a)
END PROGRAM almatrix
```

I understood that instead of

```
ALLOCATE(a(n+1,n+1))
```

this

```
ALLOCATE(a(n+1,n+1),STAT=err)
IF(err /= 0) STOP
```

would prevent crashing. It didn't, however. Why?
I tried to look at similar problems, but so far they haven't helped. 
I tried to compile with `-Wall, -g, -fcheck=all`, as suggested in another answer, but those didn't give me warnings.

I've also noticed before, that unlike with C, Fortran usually does not give bus errors when using small dynamic arrays and not deallocating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't directly with the `allocate` statement, but with accessing the resulting array.  [Note also that that an array 181x181 is not "large".]  As there is nothing wrong with the allocation, `err` will indeed be zero.

From that `allocate` one is left with an array `a` which has elements `a(1,1)`, `a(2,1)`, ..., `a(n+1,1)`, ..., `a(n+1,n+1)`.  So, `a(0,0)` (the first access in the loop) is not valid.

There are two options: request that the array elements be `a(0,0)` to `a(n,n)` as the loop wants, or change the loop:

```
allocate(a(0:n,0:n))
```

or

```
do i=1,n+1
  do j=1,n+1
    a(j,i) = 0  ! Note I've changed the order to Fortran-friendly
  end od
end do
```

Finally, those loops aren't even necessary:

```
allocate(a(0:n,0:n))
a = 0.
```

or even

```
allocate(a(0:n,0:n), source=0.)
```

if you have a compiler later than Fortran 95.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot that Fortran automatically starts intexing from 1. Although do you have any idea as to why doesn't the problem arise with smaller matrices?

Comment: @swirld: Well, 180**4*4 (size in bytes of your array) might be a limit where the platform memory allocator (malloc()) switches to another algorithm, e.g. getting memory via mmap() instead of brk(), and thus a(0,0) is not mapped instead of "merely" an access outside the array. Or something like that. In any case, if you had compiled with array bounds checking (-fcheck=bounds) the error would have been caught with smaller arrays as well. Or used valgrind or some other memory debugging tool.